# RequireJS Not Executing all Files

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I've designed this application to have a main.js file, which is executed on all pages. Where applicable, I am creating JavaScript files per page. The per-page JS is executing fine, but I notice main.js often only loads on a hard refresh which included with a per-page javascript file. I'll illustrate the setup below:

```
<script src="/admin/js/require.config.js"></script>
<script src="/admin/js/lib/require.js" data-main="./app/user/form"></script>
```

**require.config.js**

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: '/admin/js',
    paths: {
        main: 'app/main',
        bootstrap: 'lib/bootstrap',
        "datatables.net": 'lib/jquery.datatables',
        datepicker: 'lib/bootstrap-datetimepicker',
        dropzone: 'lib/dropzone',
        moment: 'lib/moment',
        notify: 'lib/bootstrap-notify',
        paper: 'lib/paper-dashboard',
        jquery: 'lib/jquery',
        select: 'lib/bootstrap-select',
        sortable: 'lib/Sortable.min',
        swal: 'lib/sweetalert2',
        switchTags: 'lib/bootstrap-switch-tags',
        wizard: 'lib/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min',
        validate: 'lib/jquery.validate.min',
        yummySearch: '/yummy/js/yummy-search',
        zxcvbn: 'lib/zxcvbn'
    },
    shim:{
        bootstrap:{
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        validate: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        wizard:{
            deps: ['bootstrap'] 
        },
        select:{
            deps: ['bootstrap']
        },
        datepicker:{
            deps: ['bootstrap','moment']
        },
        switchTags:{
            deps: ['bootstrap']
        },
        paper: {
            deps: ['bootstrap','switchTags']
        },
        notify: {
            deps: ['jquery','bootstrap']
        },
        "datatables.net": {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        main: {
            deps: ['paper','notify','moment','datepicker','swal']
        }
    },
    deps: ['main']
};
```

**main.js**

```
require(['jquery','swal','yummySearch','notify'], function($, swal) {
    console.log('does not always execute');
});
```

**app/user/form.js**

```
define(['jquery','swal','validate','datatables.net'], function($,swal) {
    console.log('will always run when loaded via data-main');
})
```

I am open to redoing this architecture if there are better ways, but would like to at least figure out this problem I am experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, **deps** property in the `requirejs` config is an array of dependencies to load. Useful when `require` is defined as a config object before `require.js` is loaded, and you want to *specify dependencies to load as soon as require() is defined*. Saying that, it only happens once, exactly when the `require.js` is loaded and is the reason your `main.js` only execute once.

Note that using **deps** is just like doing a `require([])` call to any other module, but done as soon as `require.js` is loaded and the loader has processed the configuration.

If you want your `main.js` to run on every page, then you will need to manually `required`

**app/user/form.js**

```
define(['main','jquery','.... other deps'], function(main, $, others) {
    console.log('main will always run');
})
```

Comment: I had been trying to avoid that, but it is the route I've gone with in the interim.